# Polynomial inequality proof

Tags: inequality, polynomials

Prove $(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)(1-d)>1-a-b-c-d$ and $ a,b,c,d$ are real and between 0 and 1.

I can do this with
$$(1-a)(1-b)>1-a-b  \\
1-a-b+ab>1-a-b  \\
ab>0  $$

But with $c$ and $d$, this becomes much more difficult. Can someone nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: Now, $(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)>(1-a-b)(1-c)=1-a-b-c+ca+bc>1-a-b-c$

Comment: But it wouldn't be (1−a)(1−b)(1−c)>(1−a−b)(1−c), It would be (1−a)(1−b)(1−c)>(1−a−b−c). Which is different, isn't it?

Comment: As $c<1,1-c>0$ multiply either sides of $(1-a)(1-b)>1-a-b$ by $1-c$

Answer (score 2):

Claim: $(1−a)(1−b)(1−c)(1−d)>1−a−b−c−d $
and $ a,b,c,d$ are real lying between 0 and 1.

You have: 
$(1−a)(1−b)> 1−a−b+ab>1−a−b$ for any $a,b \in R$

$ab>0$

So,

$(1−a)(1−b)(1−c)(1−d)=[1-(a+b-ab)][1-(c+d-cd)]$
$                    >1-(a+b-ab)-(c+d-cd)$    ( as $0<a(1-b) + b <1$ and $0<c(1-d) + d <1$)
$ > 1-a-b-c-d$

Answer (score 0):

(1$-$a)(1$-$b)(1$-$c)(1$-$d)>1-a-b-c-d[we consider this true]

- 1$-$(a+b+c+d)+(ab+bc+cd+...........ac)$-$(abc+bcd+cda+abd)+abcd>1-a-b-c-d
- ab+bc+cd+da+db+ac+abcd>abc+bcd+cda+dab[we have to show this]
- that is equivalant to ab(1$-$c)+bc(1$-$d)+cd(1$-$a)+da(1$-$b)+db+ac+abcd>0
- now ab>0 and c<1$\longrightarrow$1$-$c>0 so ab(1$-$c)>0.similarly we can prove the rest part.so the above inequality is true

Comment: nice one krishan.i hope you are a good inequality solver

Comment: i answered it first nicely. so fix it there now.shame of you all

Comment: manasi you are a bad inequality solver